# Is there a non-pointed simple integral modular fusion category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories, vertex-algebras, modular-tensor-categories

The weakly group-theoretical conjecture (supporting a negative answer to [ENO11, Question 2]) states as follows:
*Statement 1*:  Every integral fusion category is weakly group-theoretical.

We wonder whether Statement 1 can be deduced from its following simple case.
*Statement 2*: Every simple integral fusion category is weakly group-theoretical.

We proved in [LPR22, Theorem 5.8] that Statement 2 can be reformulated in the following nice way:
*Statement 3*: Every simple integral modular fusion category is pointed.

This leads to the following question:
**Question**: Is there a non-pointed simple integral modular fusion category?
We checked by computer assistance that there is no one at rank less than $12$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403397/34538)).

*Bonus question*: Is it true that Statement 2 implies Statement 1?

The ground field is always assumed to be the complex field $\mathbb{C}$.

---

A well-known open problem asks whether every modular tensor category is equivalent to $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathcal{V})$ with $\mathcal{V}$ a vertex operator algebra. This leads to the following question:

**Question bis**: Is there a vertex operator algebra $\mathcal{V}$ such that $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathcal{V})$ is a non-pointed simple integral modular fusion category?

The framework of vertex operator algebras could provide an easier way to answer such a question.

---

*References*
[ENO11] P. Etingof, D. Nikshych, and V. Ostrik, Weakly group-theoretical and solvable fusion categories, Adv. Math., 226 (2011), pp. 176–205.
[LPR22] Z. Liu, S. Palcoux, Y. Ren, Interpolated family of non group-like simple integral fusion rings of Lie type, arXiv:2102.01663.